# jQuery how to select iframe in Modal Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to select the closest iframe with jQuery for modal popup. There are a lot of these windows so, I'd like to select the nearest iframe. I'd expect closest() to work, but no luck. I am using this popup http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">Hello</div>
<div class="modal-popup" style="display: none;">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bjj58nbAMK8"></iframe>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function(event) {
     $('.modal-popup').bPopup({
       followSpeed: 200,
       speed: 200,
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the related iframe you need to get the immediately following sibling using `.next()` then use `.find()` to target the `iframe`, like :

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
    var modal  = $(this).next('.modal-popup');
    var iframe = modal.find('iframe');

    modal.bPopup({
       followSpeed: 200,
       speed: 200,
    });
});
```